# How Jmeter calculates response time of a sample under while controller

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, do-while

I am using while controller in script which will iterate until the required string found in the response. Now , I want to understand how response time is calculated by JMeter for this request. Is it the the response time of last iteration or the summation of all iterations under while loop. Please help. I want to get the summarized response time of all iterations

Answer (score 0):

Concept of a request / response for JMeter does not change wether you find your string or not. So given this depending on what listener you use, it will show you average, summation etc accordingly.

Summary or aggregation controller does show summation, so you might have to capture this using a custom listener. Or if you can multiply average with total transactions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will be as many requests as While Controller iterations, each request will have a separate entry in the [.jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#csvlogformat).

[image]

If you need to have only one result with the cumulative duration of all the requests which were executed by the While Controller you need to put the While Controller under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) and tick `Generate parent sample` box:

[image]

This way you will get one "Transaction Controller" sampler which response time will be the sum of all child requests response times:

[image]